# Recommendations for DotNetNuke ecommerce module and payment processor for selling software components

Tags: e-commerce, dotnetnuke, payment-processing

I am looking to add an ecommerce module to sell software components to my website. The website uses Dotnetnuke 6 / SQL Server and I have an HSBC business account that I would like to receive payment into.

I'm wondering if anyone has any recommendations for a good DotNetNuke ecommerce module first of all. One that is suited to selling software components. For instance, a user should be able to access their components (once payment processed) and download directly from the site. They should be able to access the download link for a specific period of time (e.g. 1 year) and receive updates during this timeframe. When the subscription time expires they should be emailed with a notification to renew.

Payment processing seems to be a bit of a dark art - I read that HSBC provides an API direct to business accounts, however are there any DotNetNuke modules that cater for this? The last thing I want is a professional website, product and a shabby ecommerce module that redirects customers to paypal!!

Many thanks,

Comment: In the end I went with FastSpring, which is a third party ecommerce provider. Means I can short-cut to a working, secure store with multiple languages, currencies and cards. I've integrated to my DNN site by just linking to a custom-styled page within Fastspring. Thanks for your answers though!

Answer (score 3):

Try [DNNspot e-commerce](http://www.dnnspot.com/Modules/DotNetNuke-Shopping-Cart) the free download is full featured for up to 4 products.

Supports electronic delivery of software, and has the ability to call an external web service should you want to write your own licensing generator or connect it with something else.  It works with PayPal, PayPal Pro and Authorize .Net.

OR you can use something like Digital River (not a DNN module)

I think Smith Cart also has support for electronic deliverables.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, looking into its, its the integration to payment processor thats the most important thing. Do you know if I have to pay for these services? (regular payment subscription I mean, I would assume a % payment for every transaction)

Comment: Paypal standard is free but the transaction has to occur at paypal. Paypal Pro is monthly $30.  I think Authorize .Net is also a monthly statement fee.  (plus the %'s obviously)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at NBStore, http://nbstore.codeplex.com/. It's an open source E-Commerce module that's very well done.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at AspDotNetStorefront - it powers over 10,000 stores and provides for digital downloads.

This can be used with DotNetNuke using an extension we developed called InnestoNuke.  You can see videos at http://www.InnestoNuke.com/videos/